# Unable to get into edit mode when selecting object, and need to bake multiple textures into single PNG image

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

For some reason, when I select everything in my blend,(not including lights and camera), I can't go into edit mode. However, when I select the individual parts, I can. I also can't join all of the objects together, even after selecting all, Duplicating, then hitting command J on mac. Therefore, I cannot bake all 20 of my textures together, which is my main goal. One of my textures, which is imported, is pre-baked, and my model is also pre-made. I know that I have a ton of problems, but if someone could help me out, that would be great. I am brand new to Blender, so please give a step-by-step solution. Also, I am using version 2.79, and I am on Mac.

Comment: Also, I don't know if I was clear about this in the question, but I need to combine my 20 textures into a single PNG image containing all of my textures.

Comment: Blender 2.79 you can only go to edit mode when you select one object... Multiple object to edit mode is a feature of Blender 2.8X

Comment: Do you know how I can join all of my separate objects into one single object, and THEN go into edit mode? I tried using commando J after duplicating my object, but for some reason, It didn't work.